# How to set TOOL_CHAIN_TAG while compiling EDK2

Tags: command-line, compiling

I am trying to compile EDK2 following [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/EDK2) instructions. I am using GCC 4.8.4. I know I didn't set `TOOL_CHAIN_TAG` correctly in WHERE_EVER_EDK2_IS/Conf/target.txt because when I typed build, it gave this error:

```
 'No command 'build' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pbuild' from package 'pbuilder-scripts' (universe)
 Command 'xbuild' from package 'mono-xbuild' (main)
 Command 'sbuild' from package 'sbuild' (universe)
 Command 'guild' from package 'guile-2.0-libs' (main)
 Command 'buildd' from package 'buildd' (universe)
 Command 'bwild' from package 'bacula-director-common' (main)
build: command not found'
```

I found another Ask Ubuntu question that said this command would work if `TOOL_CHAIN_TAG` was set correctly. Using GCC 4.8.4, what do I set the `TOOL_CHAIN_TAG` in WHERE_EVER_EDK2_IS/Conf/target.txt?

EDIT:
Thanks, Yurii. That seemed to fix half the problem, but it still doesn't know what I mean when I changed the TOOL_CHAIN_TAG to GCC4.8.4. What do I change the TOOL_CHAIN_TAG to so the computer understands it???

Comment: Rather than editing, please comment on the answer if something helps.

Comment: Rrgh. Why are there so many crazy rules and then when I have a serious question nobody answers and they just tell me this question is wrong. How can a question be wrong??

Comment: well it has been answered...

Comment: No it hasn't. I asked 'Using GCC 4.8.4, what do I set the TOOL_CHAIN_TAG in WHERE_EVER_EDK2_IS/Conf/target.txt?' Nobody answered that.

Answer (score -1):

It looks that you forgot to run one of the following commands.

```
make -C BaseTools
. edksetup.sh BaseTools
```

Pay attention to dot.